# How to get web url content using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used Webrequest in c# to get url Content. Then how to get url content using JavaScript/ Jquery please help to get url content...

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("https://api.pcpartpicker.com/api/2015.1/part/categories/?apikey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX");//Any Other Google Https Address
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
```

This code is working and i got data from that url and how we write this code in Javascript

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get external webpages content in your site with javascript.

only js,images formats are allowed from external source into your site

Comment: Is there any alternative to get data from web url's

Comment: you C# itsself send the url as parameter and read it in server and print it

Comment: if the content type is json/js means you can directly use ajax call

Comment: and it return XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied. Exception in IE inspect element..

Comment: yes it is not allowing it is allowing with .js extensions only

Comment: Can you have the code in a fiddle if I provide with my url

Answer (score 1):

> `You can try this code`

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        return xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false );
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

Comment: i gave url in xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false ); but it's not getting any data..

Comment: i am waiting for your replay